# Can't ask this question on information security "This looks like spam"

Tags: support, asking-questions, spam-detection

It's a long question is that why? Even tried just pasting the question here, wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you pastebin the text and link it here? If you have a large base64/36 string or hash, that could be why.

Comment: Does it have CJK characters?

Comment: good idea Easterly, Here is the actual question: still won't let me post to meta or information security [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FpZfzFJv)

Comment: looks normal to me

Comment: Try posting the first paragraph and then editing in the rest. Also, "example.com is a phishing scam" might be the part that triggers the block; it looks much like spam itself.  (Spammers love calling their own offers "scam")

Answer (score 11):

As you noticed, we have automatic spam filtering in place. On longer posts, it *can* get overzealous and block legitimate submissions. The exact details of the algorithm aren't public for obvious reasons, but we can usually tell you what happened if you [contact us](/contact) and include the content of the post. Posting on meta generally works as well.

I see you were able to work around this specific situation already, but I figured I'd leave a more general response for anyone else running into a similar issue.